# Iniciar serviço com TimerTask

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Estou a tentar iniciar um serviço de notificação Android com o TimerTask mas retorna-me o seguinte erro:

```
02-03 16:06:00.164  15051-15379/com.celiogarcia.setapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3845)
        at com.celiogarcia.setapp.Sentado$RingNotification.run(Sentado.java:70)
        at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Eis o meu código ... Talvez vocês poderão ver o que está escuro para mim ...

```
public class Sentado extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sentado);

               ...
            }
        });
    }

    public class RingNotification extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startService(new Intent(Sentado.this, NotificationService.class));
            }
     }


    public void setTimer(){
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                TimerTask ringNotify = new RingNotification();



                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(ringNotify, 60000, 60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque todo o stacktrace gerado pra facilitar a identificação do problema.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro feito...

Comment: Eu acredito que o erro está no "contexto" mas a verdade é que não vejo outra forma de fazer passar o parâmetro ...

Comment: Isto é uma aplicação Android? Porque é que está utilizando o método `public static void main`?

Comment: Sim. Neste exemplo eu usei esse método para simplificar a explicação do meu problema, por fundo, o resultado que der neste exemplo, é mesmo que terei no meu projecto...

Comment: O que é a classe `Sentado`?

Comment: É a classe Mãe....

Comment: Mas qual é o seu tipo? É Activity ou outro?

Comment: É uma Activity ...